# how to send parameter values to url in titnanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

How to add parameters to the url in titaninum

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
```

user name and password

abcd is user name abcd@123 is password

```
var authstr = 'Basic ' +Titanium.Utils.base64encode('abcd'+':'+ 'abcd@123'); 
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authstr);   

xhr.open("GET","http:\\domain name .. .. ");
    alert (xhr.open);
Ti.API.info("result " + xhr);
```

I need to appened my url with username and password!

and  i need to print in total url in titaninum !

Answer (score 0):

I generally create the url by concatenating the params into the url like this..

```
  var api_url = "http://domain/?paramname=" + param + '&paramname2=' + param2;

  xhr.open('GET', api_url);
  xhr.send();
```

where param and param2 are variables holding the proper data